# VueJs Can't resolve component in correct path with filename

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, webpack

Into `resources/js/components`, I have `welcome.vue` file with this content:

```js
<template>
    <div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

}
</script>
```

i defined folders into `webpack.mix.js` with this configuration:

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

mix
    .js('resources/js/main.js','public/js')
    .js('resources/js/service-providers.js','public/js')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss','public/css')
    .webpackConfig({
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    //'@Services': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/services'),
                    //'@Components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/components')
                    '@Service': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/services'),
                    '@Component': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/components')
                }
            }
        }
    );
```

`service-providers.js` file content:

```js
require('@Service/welcome-page')
```

folders structure:

[image]

now, when i try to add component to `VueJs` with this code which that is into `welcome-page.js`:

```js
Vue.component('welcome-page', () => import('@Component/welcome'))
```

i get this error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/service-providers.js 1:0-33
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@Services/welcome-page' in '/var/www/resources/js'
```

Comment: Typos? `@Service` vs `@Services` and `@Component` vs `@Components`

Comment: @brombeer i don't think, i checked befor

Comment: Your alias is named `@Service`, you use `@Services` in `require('@Services/welcome-page')`

Comment: @brombeer i changed that to `@Service`, but i have still error

Comment: @brombeer i figured out i have this error in console before mix `Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/root/.npm/_logs'` this error can be cause of this problem?

Comment: Why do you use CommonJS in service-providers.js?

Comment: @bigless that's for integrating `laravel` with `vuejs`